# Is there a general guideline for minimizing $\sup_{y\in H}F(\;\cdot\;,y)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space and $F:H^2\to\mathbb R$. Is there a general guideline for minimizing $\sup_{y\in H}F(\;\cdot\;,y)$?

Since the question is rather abstract, feel free to impose any addition assumption you like. For example, $F(\;\cdot\;,y)$ being sufficiently regular. If this is too hard, I'd also be interested in finding and minimizing suitable upper bounds.

*Remark*: This is the concrete instance of the problem I'm interested in: [Can we conclude $\sup_g\int f_1g\le\sup_g\int f_2g$ from $\int f_1\le\int f_2$ in this situation?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/347325/91890).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are dealing with is of the form
$$
\inf_{x\in H}\sup_{y\in H} F(x,y).
$$
If $F$ is convex in $x$ and concave in $y$, this is a **saddle point problem** and you can find a lot of information under this buzzword. Note that there is the very important special case of "linear saddle point problems" which arise if you minimize a quadratic function over a linear constraint, but also non-linear saddle point problems are a thing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think the instance of the problem in the link is of this form? (At least if $r$ is chosen such that the dependence on $(w_i)_{i\in I}$ is nice.)

Comment: Honestly, I don't know and the problem looks too involved that I would start to invest my time, sorry.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I've tried to reformulate the problem in a simplified manner: https://mathoverflow.net/q/347894/91890. Maybe you can take a look.